# Route [ ] not defined

Tags: laravel, routes

i wan to be able to dlete a price whereby upon clicking the delete button a modal appears which then shows the yes or no delete buttons.here is the ajax function in the view which contains the delete button

```
function removeogFuelPriceModel(id)
 {
$.ajax({
    url: "{{route('industryfuelprice.edit.modal')}}",
    type: 'post',
    'headers': {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },
    data: {
        'id': id,
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $("#showEditInventoryModal").html(response);
        $("#showMsgModal").modal('show');
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    }
  });
}
```

here is a div inside the modal which contains the id which redirects to the delete ajax function

```
<div class="row"
                    style="width: 100%; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
                    <div class="col col-m-12 text-center">
                        <button type="button"
                        class="btn bg-primary primary-button"
                        **onclick="deleteData({{$oilgas->id}})"**
                        data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                        <button type="button"
                        class="btn btn-danger primary-button"
                        data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

here is the ajax function in the modal

```
   function deleteData(id) {

        const url = "{{ route('industryoilgas.destroyFuelprice', ['model_id' => "MODEL_ID"]) }}".replace("MODEL_ID", id);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function (response) {  
                $("#showMsgModal").modal('hide')
                $("#showEditInventoryModal").html(response)
                $('#showMsgModal').modal('show');
                $("#addFuelPrice").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#addFuelPrice").css({"cursor":"pointer;"});
                
                loadFuelPrice();
            }, error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.message)

            }
        });
    }
```

here are my routes

```
Route::post('show-industry-fuel-price-edit-modal','IndustryOilGasController@showEditModalFuelPrice')->name('industryfuelprice.edit.modal');

  Route::post('delete-fuel-price/{id}', 'IndustryOilGasController@destroyFuelprice')->name('industryoilgas.destroyFuelprice');
```

i don't understand why am getting that error

Comment: Can you share what's inside the `url` by doing a `console.log(url)`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined `removeogFuelPriceModel()` and `deleteData()` within a blade component, because an Laravel helper method cannot be resolved outside a predefined php file. In this case, you are mostly defining those methods inside a JS file which won't work properly. To address this issue, you may inject those methods inside a script layout within the blade component. I wish this could help you out!

Comment: @Arabat i havent understood..please explain in simpler terms

Comment: I said any laravel helper methods such as `route()`, `auth()` and so on, are not resolved in a javascript file where you may have defined your methods. `removeogFuelPriceModel()` and `deleteData()` should be defined in a blade file. You may refer to `tightenco/ziggy` package in order to use `route()` in a js file through the following link [link](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy)

Comment: how can i defne them in the view?

Comment: "_here is the ajax function in the view_" Sounds like they already are declared in the view

Comment: You can define them within the `script` division at the end of your blade file, like this:
`<script>
function removeogFuelPriceModel(id)
 {
$.ajax({
    url: "{{route('industryfuelprice.edit.modal')}}",
    type: 'post',
    'headers': {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },
    data: {
        'id': id,
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $("#showEditInventoryModal").html(response);
        $("#showMsgModal").modal('show');
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    }
  });
}
</script>`
The same thing for the second

Comment: @AliArabat thats what i have done and still the error keeps in coming

Comment: Could you make console.log for the url?